# Медиа-запросы css срабатывают со смещением по ширине

Tags: css, responsive

День добрый, в медиазапросах css такого вида
 `min-width: 992px and (max-width: 1023.98px)`,
 все прописанные правила работают, но срабатывание сбито по пикселям, например, вместо 768px он срабатывает на 740px,пробовал убрать все скрипты, не помогло. где проблему искать?

Comment: Возможно вы не учитываете скролл внутреннего блока? Во всех браузерах ширина скролла разная, в мобильных так вообще не учитывается.

Comment: Было бы не плохо если бы прямо в вопросе вы показали [mcve] с вашей проблемой

Comment: @kizoso, для примера, перенёс страничку на гитхаб хостинг, но там всё заработало правильно, то есть ошибка  на локальном сервере, сталкиваюсь с таким первый раз, спасибо.

Comment: Сложно дать конкретный ответ без конкретного примера, даже не могу представить что у вас там и почему

Answer (score 0):

[**телепатия on**]

Масштаб броузера, скорее всего, у вас не тот стоит и все. ) 
Поставьте 100 процентов.

[**телепатия off**]

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/390654)

Comment: @0xdb Это довольно типичная проблема с маштабом, на которую пару раз натыкался. Почти уверен что поможет. )

Comment: Уточните у торикастера комментарием прежде чем дать ответ. Ну а если есть желание пованговать, то начните ответ с прологом  вызывающим чувство уверенности   - "Надо сделать так ...". Угадали - хорошо, не угадали - ну тогда можно просто удалить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая проблема была из за того что устройство было выбрано в браузере Desktop, а не Mobile.